# Call Javascript method from code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

I have a function in Javascript which makes a label invisible. I want to call this function from the code behind. I am not able to make it invisible. Here are both the lines of code.

C# code behind:

```
          Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "MyFunction", "MyFunction();", true);
```

javascript:

```
         <script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript">
          function MyFunction()
          {
                 document.getElementById("Label8").style.display = 'none';

          }
          </script>
```

Pls let me know if there is any mistake. Looks like control is not going to method definition only.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have a clientscriptmanager on the page?

Comment: If all you are doing is setting display none, why would you not do that from the codebehind?  That would also guarantee a clean page load...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ClientID` of server control (label) in `getElementById` or set [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) to static for label and make sure the availability of html elements to script, for that you can put script tag just before *closing* tag of `body`

```
<script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      function MyFunction()
      {
          document.getElementById("<%= Label8.ClientID %>").style.display = 'none';    
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Still not working. Control is not going to method body. Is the calling method line correct?

Comment: Add script tag just before closing tag of body.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a label on your page like this;

```
<asp:Label ID="lblExample" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Hello"></asp:Label>
```

then I suggest you to use jQuery, and your js function should be like this;

```
<script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function hideLabel() 
   {
     $("#lblExample").hide();
   }
</script>
```

and finally call your js function like this in your code behind;

```
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), "hideLabel();", true);
```

If you use `ScriptManager` and`MasterPage` then call like this;

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), DateTime.Now.ToString(), "hideLabel();", true);
```

Comment: I am not able to make it invisible. ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType() is not coming in blue. Is it a problem?

Comment: Control is not going to that method in javascript.

Comment: Sanju did you used jQuery?

Comment: And c# has to accept GetType() or this.GetType(). they are same.